# SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'category' in 'field list' (SQL: update `articles` set `updated_at`)

Tags: laravel

I have two table

- articles
- categories

I have a ArticleController. I want to edit the form. But it get errors.

> SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'category' in
>   'field list' (SQL: update `articles` set `updated_at` = 2017-12-21
>   11:50:12, `category` = 1 where `id` = 1)

ArticleController.php

```
public function update(ArticleRequest $request, Article $article)
    {
        $file = $request->file('images');
        $inputs = $request->all();
        $article->categories()->sync(request('category'));

        if($file) {
            $inputs['images'] = $this->uploadImages($request->file('images'));
        } else {
            $inputs['images'] = $article->images;
            $inputs['images']['thumb'] = $inputs['imagesThumb'];

        }

        unset($inputs['imagesThumb']);
        $article->update($inputs);

        return redirect(route('articles.index'));
    }
```

This error occurred on the following line.

> $article->update($inputs);

edit.blade.php

```
<select name="category[]" class="form-control" id="category" title=" Select your a categories..." multiple>
      @foreach( $categories as $id => $name )
               <option value="{{ $id }}" {{ in_array($id , $article->categories()->pluck('id')->toArray()) ? 'selected' : '' }}>{{ $name }}</option>
      @endforeach
</select>
```

Category

```
class Category extends Model
{
    protected $fillable = ['name', 'slug'];

    public function articles()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany(Article::class);
    }
}
```

Article

```
public function categories()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany(Category::class);
    }
```

Comment: please share your model class for "Category.php" and "Article.php"

Comment: yes i have two model Category and Article.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your articles table doesn't have a column called category. Can you post your article table migration please

Comment: yes, so the error is that on your 'articles' table there is no column called 'category'

Answer (score 1):

It means that you don't have `category` column in your `articles` table. So make sure you have one or use other column name.

Also from input you are getting multiple categories, so it seems incorrect to update article with this input.

Answer (score 0):

Pay attention to this

```
<select name="category[]"
```

Perhaps you meant

```
<select name="category_id[]"
```

Comment: Maybe your forgot add `protected $fillable = ['category_id'];` in Article Model?

Comment: I want to get multi select the lists.

Comment: `<select name="category_id[]"` and in ArticleController.php replace `category` with `category_id`

Answer (score 0):

Its because you don't have a $fillable array on your Article model so other values from the request are leaking through to mass assignment.