# SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'category' in 'field list' in laravel 5.4

Tags: laravel

What is this error? I try for 9.5 hours, but I'm getting an error.

> SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'category' in
>   'field list' (SQL: update `articles` set `updated_at` = 2017-12-22
>   00:28:36, `category` = 1 where `id` = 5)

ArticleController

```
public function update(ArticleRequest $request, Article $article)
    {
        $file = $request->file('images');
        $inputs = $request->all();
        $article->categories()->sync(request('category'));

        if($file)
        {
            $inputs['images'] = $this->uploadImages($request->file('images'));
        }
        else
        {
            $inputs['images'] = $article->images;
            $inputs['images']['thumb'] = $inputs['imagesThumb'];
        }

        unset($inputs['imagesThumb']);
        $article->update($inputs);

        return redirect(route('articles.index'));
    }
```

Article.php

```
class Article extends Model
{

    public function categories()
        {
            return $this->belongsToMany(Category::class);
        }
}
```

Category.php

```
class Category extends Model
{
    protected $fillable = ['name', 'slug'];

    public function articles()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany(Article::class);
    }
}
```

edit.blade.php

```
<select name="category[]" class="form-control" id="category" title=" Select your category..." multiple>
     @foreach( $categories as $id => $name )
             <option value="{{ $id }}" {{ in_array($id , $article->categories()->pluck('id')->toArray()) ? 'selected' : '' }}>{{ $name }}</option>
     @endforeach
</select>
```

I want to edit the article form.

Comment: The error message is quite straightforward. Are you sure you have the `category` column/field in your database table?

Comment: Yes i create `category` field in my database table but it get error

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because  it's the same question as in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47921142/sqlstate42s22-column-not-found-1054-unknown-column-category-in-field-list/47921229#47921229

Comment: what should I do???

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have category as a field in your request, and if not filtered by `$fillable` array then the field will be passed to the database table for storage even though you don't have a category column.

either;
a) create a fillable array and only include the relevant columns
b) use `$request->only()` to pass just the required fields from the request
c) `unset` category from input as you have done for `imagesThumb`